# dry up active record model validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

While the following segment of code works, I have started exploring a better way to DRY this up. Anyone have a better idea of how to structure this? I appreciate your help.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :remote_addr, :web_browser, :operating_system, presence: true

  validates :age_verification, presence: { message: "You must be at least 18 years old to register for this application" }

  validates :email_address,
    allow_nil: false,
    allow_blank: false,
    presence: { message: "A valid email address is required" },
    uniqueness: {
      case_sensitive: false,
      message: "This email address has been previously registered"
    },
    email_format: {
      check_mx: true,
      mx_message: "This email address has a bad domain",
      message: "This email address must be formatted properly"
    }

end
```

Comment: The trouble is, you're not repeating much. You could use [internationalization](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models) on your AR models to extract error messages. Do you need `allow_blank/nil` on `email_address`? Will `presence: true` not suffice?

Comment: true, very true. maybe I am emphasizing DRY too much.  I mean it's still readable.  Hmmm... this could be overkill.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may:

1. Move custom messages to I18n file, more [info](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models), example:

config/locales/en.yml

```
en:
  errors:
    attributes:
      age_verification:
        blank: 'You must be at least 18 years old to register for this application'
      email_address:
        blank: 'A valid email address is required'

  activerecord:
    errors:
      messages:
        invalid_email_address: 'This email address must be formatted properly'
        email_address_not_routable: 'This email address has a bad domain'

  activemodel:
    errors:
      messages:
        invalid_email_address: 'This email address must be formatted properly'
        email_address_not_routable: 'This email address has a bad domain'
```

and join presence validation, age_verification, email fields with other

2 in **validates** :**email_address**, really necessary to check on **allow_nil** and **allow_blank** and **presence**? Because validate email format overlaps them, ie blank and nil not accepted as valid value. For data consistency rather use database indexes and column constraint.

So I be do like this:

```
  validates_presence_of :remote_addr, :web_browser,
                        :operating_system, :age_verification, :email_address

  validates :email_address, uniqueness:   { case_sensitive: false },
                            email_format: { check_mx: true }
```

move error messages to en.yml file (see above), and add create migration to table

```
change_column <tables>, :email, null: false
add_index <tables>, :email, unique: true
```

Comment: I like this quite a bit, but how would I add an error message for the `email_format` ?

Comment: also @Vakiliy here is the valid email gem I am using :: https://github.com/alexdunae/validates_email_format_of

Comment: :invalid_email_address - for invalid  email, :email_address_not_routable - for :mx_message, more info https://github.com/alexdunae/validates_email_format_of/blob/master/lib/validates_email_format_of.rb#L29

Comment: @chrishough ie path for message should be en.errors.messages.invalid_email_address in yml notation

Comment: I just made a few edits @vakiliy, what do you think?